# High Requirement Games suddenly stopped working

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, graphics-card, gaming

I upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 8, just about a month ago. I installed all latest drivers including motherboard & grapahic card drivers. All my high requirement games, eg. Call of Duty Black Ops 2, Sleeping Dogs, etc were working fine. Now suddenly, they've stopped working. They start for a second or two, and then it says that they've stopped responding. Also, once my windows is booted, the startup objects take too long to load. I've actually expiremented with many boot settings, and changed the startup objects, startup services, etc. I once tried a game in windows' safe mode, and it at least started, but was too slow. Please tell me what I can do to solve this sudden performance downgrade of my windows.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not upgrading to Windows 8.1?

Comment: Why don't you put it back with `System Restore`? If you still have problems it's probally a hardware problem or something.